# I cannot connect to shinyapps.io Publishing Account in R Studio. I see an error

Tags: r, rstudio, shinyapps, rsconnect

I am not able to connect to my Publishing account on R studio.

1. I go to the path Tools -> Global Options -> Publishing -> Connect
2. I choose ShinyApps.io and I paste the command that I copied from shinyapps.io dashboard (command from STEP 2 – AUTHORIZE ACCOUNT)
3. I click on Connect Account but I see this error

[image]

4. I tried connecting from R Studio Console using rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name, token, secret) and I got the below error.

> "Error in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")) :
> number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)"

I tried connecting by disabling Firewall. It did not work.

I have tried looking online for other troubleshooting steps but I could not understand what the actual issue is.

Can you please help me?

I am using **R studio Version 1.3.959** and **R version 3.5.2**

Comment: Assuming this is a paid account, contact RStudio support?

Comment: No this is not a paid account. I am using free services.

Comment: Try asking at https://community.rstudio.com/ someone at the company there might still help you.

Comment: Ok I will try asking here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error when you click connect.
It shows:

> Error in the library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
> `DLL ‘openssl’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?`

This error follows the instruction i.e install the given package. In my case '**OpenSSL**' was missing so I installed it and it worked.